# .htaccess redirect stripping off URL parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution that works.

Basically I want to redirect http://www.domain.com/products?view=products (ONLY this) to http://www.domain.com/products

Because I'm trying to redirect "products" to "products", the other solutions I've tried always cause a redirect loop. I really just want to remove the "?view=products" in this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=products$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` in target URL strip off query string. Make sure this is your very first rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't quite work as expected. The URL it redirects to is http://www.domain.com/home/myuser/public_html/products.